# Want Javascript Button's images to swap independently of one another

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Currently I have code that causes images to change when clicked, but this code is in a php HTML loop so things have gotten tricky, and clicking one toggle makes the toggle activate for every single story, since it's operating based off the CSS. How do I get them to swap independently?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".buy").toggle(
      function() { $(".buy").css("background-image", "url(play3.png)");},
  function() { $(".buy").css("background-image", "url(play.png)");});
</script>
     <div class="layer1"> <span class="buy" id="{STORIES.story_id}6">
     <input type="image"   class="test"></input></span>
```

Comment: your input should be like `<input type="image" class="test" />` not the way you have it `<input type="image" class="test"></input>`

Answer (score 1):

Use $(this) instead of $(".buy") inside the function , $(this) specifically refers to that particular button, whereas $(".buy") refers to all the elements with class 'buy'.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".buy").toggle(
      function() { $(this).css("background-image", "url(play3.png)");},
  function() {$(this).css("background-image", "url(play.png)");});
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, uhhhhghgg, that easy eh, been looking at all the wrong stuff. Thanks!

Comment: also do you guys have any ideas on how to allow one to be toggled at a time?

Comment: This is not toggling the clicked element only, is it toggling all the elements?